# Cannot delete child table records because parent table is mutating, foreign key on delete cascade failed

Tags: oracle19c

I have two tables - parent table (Table A) and child table (Table B). I added a foreign key on delete cascade in my child table so that related records in child table will be deleted if we delete the record from parent table. This should work fine. However, my child table has a after delete trigger which will update the parent table if users delete records from child table. This trigger fired when I delete records from parent table. So it give me an error said parent table is mutating so I can't delete anything from parent table.

Is there a way to handle this situation? I need to delete the records in child table when records in parent table is deleted. Also, I need to update the parent table if there's delete in child table.